# Reputation limit

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Is there a limit on the reputation one can build in a single day? I had added on 209 reputation, and the next up-vote gave me 6 points. None of the up-votes after that contributed.

Comment: Yes, it exist a limit of 200 rep in the GMT day. This limit does not include some activity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a limit of 200 reputation per day from upvotes for all users. Official source is here:

[How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)